# How to generate random vector from specific user defined range?

Tags: matlab, octave, random

I want to generate the random vector containing the number from the user defined range. For example:
numbers = [1 2 4 10]
The random vector should always consist of these numbers. Eg. rand_num= [1 1 2 10 5 2 10]
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let

```
numbers = [1 2 4 10]; %// population to sample from
N = 5; %// how many samples to take
```

You can use [`randsample`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/stats/randsample.html) (Statistics Toolbox):

```
rand_num = randsample(numbers, N, true); %// "true" means sample with replacement
```

or [`randi`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/randi.html) (standard function):

```
rand_num = numbers(randi(numel(numbers), 1, N));
```