# MATLAB - Generate Random Vectors

Tags: matlab, vector, random

I have 2 vectors which I want to generate randomly. The 2 vectors are input and target vector below that will be passed as parameters to the perceptron algorithm.

```
input = [-1 -1 1 1; -1 1 1 -1]; 
target =[1 0 0 1];
```

The vectors will be between -1 and 1. I tried using the solution from [How to generate random vector from specific user defined range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24620729/how-to-generate-random-vector-from-specific-user-defined-range) however was not able to get this to work.

Comment: Should the numbers be between -1 to 1 or should they be only -1, 0, 1?

Comment: it will be only -1, 0, 1

Comment: You could show what you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use randi:

```
input = -2 + randi(3, 2, 4)
output = -2 + randi(3, 1, 4)
```

Output:

```
input =

   1   1  -1   0
  -1  -1   1  -1

output =

   0  -1  -1   1
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `randint` function to generate random integer values and specify your desired range (which in your case is [-1,...,1]).

```
r=randint(1,5,[-1,1]); %Generate a 1*5 vector with values between -1 to 1

r =
   -1     1     1     0     1
```

You might get this warning,depending on yuor Matlab version:

"Warning: This is an obsolete function and may be removed in the future. Please use RANDI instead. "
in this case, use `randi` function instead as suggested.

Comment: *may be removed in the future*? It has been removed and it was a part of "Communications System Toolbox".